# How to optimize query

Tags: sql, optimization, cross-apply

I am using Linq2Sql as an ORM and experiencing following problem: I have 2 tables, lets call them:

1. client (id, name)
2. client_action (id, clientid, date)

The `client` table contains clients, and `client_action` contains log of user's actions and i need just first of them.

There was a linq2sql query (with paging and sorting), that was resulting in the following sql:

```
SELECT TOP (10) /* columns here */
FROM (
    SELECT /* columns here */
    FROM [dbo].[client] AS [t0]
    CROSS APPLY ((
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            ) AS [t8]
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT [t9].[source]
            FROM [action] AS [t9]
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT MIN([t10].[actionID]) AS [value], [t10].[ClientID]
                FROM [client_action] AS [t10]
                GROUP BY [t10].[clientID]
                ) AS [t11] ON [t9].[ID] = [t11].[value]
            WHERE [t0].[ID] = [t11].[ClientID]
            ) AS [t12])
    ) AS [t17]
WHERE /* filter for fields from the client table */
ORDER BY [t17].[date_created] DESC
```

There was a logical error in that query and I changed it. Now the SQL generated looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP (10) /* columns here */
FROM (
    SELECT /* columns here */
    FROM (
        SELECT /* columns here */
        FROM [dbo].[client] AS [t0]
        CROSS APPLY ((
                SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                ) AS [t3]
            OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT [t7].[value]
                FROM (
                    SELECT [t5].[ClientID], (
                        SELECT TOP (1) [t6].[ID]
                        FROM [client_action] AS [t6]
                        WHERE [t5].[clientID] = [t6].[clientID]
                        ORDER BY [t6].[date_created]
                        ) AS [value]
                    FROM (
                        SELECT [t4].[clientID]
                        FROM [client_action] AS [t4]
                        GROUP BY [t4].[clientID]
                        ) AS [t5]
                    ) AS [t7]
                WHERE [t0].[ID] = [t7].[clientID]
                ) AS [t8])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [client_action] AS [t9] ON [t8].[value] = [t9].[ID]
        ) AS [t26]
    ) AS [t27]
WHERE /* filter for fields from client table */
ORDER BY [t27].[date_created] DESC
```

And the performance problem appears. I executed both queries with 'SET STATISTICS IO ON' and got interesting results:

- for the first query:

  - client table is filtered
  - 'top 10' applied
  - 'cross apply' applied for the resulting 10 records
- for the second query:

  - client table is filtered (about 10K records found)
  - 'cross apply' applied for that 10K records
  - 'top 10' applied

So it makes second query works much slower. Is there a way to 'tweak' the query so that 'cross apply' will be applied after filtering whenever possible?

The problem is that there are 2 'cross apply's and couple more joins there and it all makes it work really slow. I created indices that could improve the speed of the query but still its slow enough to be annoying.

Comment: Why not write a custom stored proc which you manually optimize, rather than rely on LINQ to SQL which is notorious for creating non-optimal sql?

Comment: What is your linq2sql statement?